# UDP write to socket and read from socket at the same time

Tags: php, sockets, udp

Server:

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL | E_STRICT);

$socket = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, SOL_UDP);

socket_bind($socket, '127.0.0.1', 11104);

$from = "";
$port = 0;
socket_recvfrom($socket, $buf, 12, 0, $from, $port);
//$buf=socket_read($socket, 2048);

echo "Received $buf from remote address $from and remote port $port" . PHP_EOL;
$msg="Sikerult";

//socket_write($socket, $msg, strlen($msg));
socket_sendto($socket, $msg, strlen($msg), 0, '127.0.0.1', 11104);
//socket_close($socket);
?>
```

client:

```
    $sock = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, SOL_UDP);
$result = socket_connect($sock, '127.0.0.1', 11104);
    $msg = "Sikerult";
    $len = strlen($msg);
        //socket_write($sock, $msg, strlen($msg));
    socket_sendto($sock, $msg, $len, 0, '127.0.0.1', 11104);
    //$buf=socket_read($sock, 2048);
    socket_recvfrom($sock, $buf, 12, 0, $from, $port);
    echo $buf;
    socket_close($sock);
?>
```

the server receives the data from the client but the client got nothing from the server and not stop running.

Answer (score 1):

The server is sending the packet back to itself, you need to pass it the port of the client, not of the server. So:

```
socket_recvfrom($socket, $buf, 12, 0, $from, $port);
socket_sendto($socket, $msg, strlen($msg), 0, $from, $port);
```